# Dynamic loading of module/routes in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm developing a workflow based angular app, from an API I'm getting this response:

```
[
    {
        workFlowNodeName : "Workflow Node 1",
        tasks:[
            {
                taskId: "<encrypted-task-id>",
                taskName: "Task 1",
                dueDate: "21-12-2023",
                status: "completed",
                action:"main-module/workflow-node-1/task-1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        workFlowNodeName : "Workflow Node 2",
        tasks:[
            {
                taskId: "<encrypted-task-id>",
                taskName: "Task 2",
                dueDate: "21-12-2023",
                status: "todo",
                action:"main-module/workflow-node-2/task-2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm rendering this on the component using this code

```
<div *for="let node of workflownode" >
        <h1>{{node.workFlowNodeName}}</h1>
        <div *for="let task of node.tasks" >
                <h4>{{task.taskName}}</h4>
                <button *action="goToTask(task.action)" >intiantate</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

So what I'm going to achieve is in the `gotToTask` function.

```
gotToTask(action) {
   let [module, path, component] = action.split('/');
   1. load the module from the path and create a route with action and component
   2. navigate to that.
}
```

Folder structure

```
 - main-module
    - main-module.ts
    - wokflow-node-1
      - task-1.component.ts
    - wokflow-node-2
      - task-2.component.ts
```

Can anyone provide the idea or is that possible in  angular ?

Comment: did you see this? https://medium.com/@teslenkooleg2017/dynamic-import-ngmodule-angular-13-e7183c6743c6

Comment: u prob want this ... https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules